# Recursive Insertion in a Binary Tree

Tags: c#, recursion, tree, binary-tree, insertion

Why reason the member variables LEFT and RIGHT never change when i make the recursive call?
Here's the Source Code:

```
public class C_Nodo

{
    int dato;
    C_Nodo left;
    C_Nodo right;

    public int DATO
    {
        get { return dato; }
        set { dato = value; }
    }

    public C_Nodo LEFT
    {
        get { return this.left; }
        set { this.left= value; }
    }

    public C_Nodo RIGHT
    {
        get { return this.right; }
        set { this.right = value; }
    }

    public C_Nodo(int inf)
    {
        this.dato = inf;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
}

public class C_Arbol_Bin

{   
    C_Nodo root;

    public C_Arbol_Bin()
    {
        root = null;
    }
```

Simple insertion in the root or make the recursive call

```
    public void inserta(int dat)
    {
        if (root == null)
        {
            root = new C_Nodo(dat);
        }
        else
        {
            insert_Order(this.root, dat);
        }
    }
```

Here i make the recursive insertion in ordered way depending of the value that contains the father node but RIGH and LEFT never change.

```
    public void insert_Order(C_Nodo tree, int inf)
    {
        if (tree == null)
        {
            tree = new C_Nodo(inf);
        }
        else
        {
            if (tree.DATO > inf)
            {
                insert_Order(tree.LEFT, inf);
            }
            else
            {
                insert_Order(tree.RIGHT, inf);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it looks `C`, says `C#`...what???

Comment: That's defniitley C#, Look at the get and the set values. Anyhow, what is the recursive call you make? Put breakpoints, and tell us what does the tree actually contain.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the function like

```
public void insert_Order( ref C_Nodo tree, int inf );
```

Also as this function is an auxiliary function for function `inserta` then it could be declared like `private`

Answer (score 0):

What Vlad said...
Basically the reason that the LEFT/RIGHT parts are always null is because you are passing a reference-type object by value, and then call **new C_Nodo()** on it - this creates a pointer to a new location for your object.

So you can either use Vlad's solution and pass it by reference, or you can change your **insert** and **insert_Order** methods to return the Node object and save it in the root node:

```
    public void inserta(int dat)
    {
        if (root == null)
        {
            root = new C_Nodo(dat);
        }
        else
        {
            this.root = insert_Order(this.root, dat);
        }
    }

    private C_Nodo insert_Order(C_Nodo tree, int inf)
    {
        if (tree == null)
        {
            tree = new C_Nodo(inf);
        }
        else
        {
            if (tree.DATO > inf)
            {
                tree.LEFT = insert_Order(tree.LEFT, inf);
            }
            else
            {
                tree.RIGHT = insert_Order(tree.RIGHT, inf);
            }
        }

        return tree;
    }
```

Check out this article for more info on references: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx